# In $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ , why is $\Gamma$ a congruence subgroup of index $3$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

In $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ , show that the group $\Gamma$ generated by $S=\begin{pmatrix}0 &-1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and  $T^2=\begin{pmatrix}1 &2 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ is a congruence subgroup of index three.

I know that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))/\Gamma(2)\simeq SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$  where $\Gamma(2)$ denotes the principal congruence subgroup of level $2$ and that the index is $6$ .

My problem is to understand why the second part follows by the correspondence theorem .

Answer (score 2):

You need to show that $\Gamma$ contains the principal congruence
subgroup $\Gamma(2)$. This has index $6$ in the modular group. But $\Gamma$
consists of $\Gamma(2)$ and also the coset of $\Gamma(2)$ generated by the matrix $S$, and so $|\Gamma:\Gamma(2)|=2$ etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help . I do not understand why the  index is two .

Comment: @AnabolicHorse Two cosets.